# Syncing Multiple SubFolders in Exchange Web Services

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

Up until now I used to just need to sync my Main Contacts folder using

SyncFolderItems()

But recently I added multiple contact sub-folders to keep contacts organized so now I'm confused as far as the syncstate that I store. I thought the sync state was like a mailbox-wide unique identifier for a given point in time, but now It looks like I need to call the SyncFolderItems() function for each subfolder and store different syncstates for each folder.

Is this true? Or am I overthinking it?

Storing one syncstate is bad as it is already I cant m imagine having to store 6 different sync states.

Has anybody had any experience with synccing multiple folders in Exchange?

Any tips, or advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Majority of all API operations in Exchange are per folder, the syncstate just tells you the synchronization state of the particular folder you have used it against. You will need to maintain a separate syncstate for every folder you want to synchronize against. Sub-folders are a separate container in this regards

> > Storing one syncstate is bad as it is already I cant m imagine having to store 6 different sync states.

ActiveSync stores a similar sync state per folder (and works on millions of devices) its just something that synchronization requires so shouldn't really be issue.

Cheers
Glen